# Calling OpenCV from a web service

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, opencv

I'm trying to call OpenCV face detection methods from inside a web service, but I'm getting various errors. Not sure if it is possible to do that or if anyone have tried it before.
Here's what I did:

1- Compile a modified sample OpenCV code at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html into a C++ DLL. the modified code is included below

```
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall DetectFaceFromLumaBuffer (char *GrayBuf, int Rows, int Cols)
{
    if (face_cascade.empty())
    {
        if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name))
        {
            return (-1);
        }
    }
    Mat LumaFrame (Rows, Cols, CV_8UC1, GrayBuf, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    int Idx = 0;
    equalizeHist(LumaFrame, LumaFrame);             /* Equalize the image histogram  */

    std::vector<Rect> DetFaces;                     /* Array of detected rectangles */

    face_cascade.detectMultiScale (LumaFrame, DetFaces, 1.1, 3, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, Size(10, 10), Size(LumaFrame.cols, LumaFrame.rows) );
    return (DetFaces.size());
}
```

2- Call the DLL's DetectFaceFromLumaBuffer() from .NET C# application using platform invoke.This works fine.

3- Call the same function from web service also using platform invoke. The local IIS crashes: IIS Express Worker Process has stopped working.

4- Comment out the line "equalizeHist(LumaFrame, LumaFrame);", the call generates an exception "SEHException was unhandled by user code"

Any ideas?
I'm using VS 2012 express and OpenCV 247

Thanks

Comment: Is your OpenCV compiled as 64bits?

Comment: Nope, as i mentioned, the same DLL work perfectly in a desktop app...

Comment: That doesn't mean much, it can run as a desktop app by defaulting to the right bitness and you can have IIS configured differently. 
Is there a way you can inspect this exception for content?

Comment: How can a compiled c++ DLL change it's own architecture at runtime?

Comment: Additionally, I'm linking with the libraries in OpenCV's x86 folder not x64

Comment: Ok, in .net 4.5 the default compilation is "Any CPU 32-bit preferred" which means that by default even on a 64bits platform, the exe runs by default in 32 bits. This is not the default on IIS, so you should either link both agains the 64bits version of OpenCV or configure your app pool in IIS to run in 32bits.